# Replacement Extruder for CR10 Pro Smart

Tags: extruder, creality-cr-10

Is the Sprite Extruder Pro Kit the correct kit to replace my extruder on my CR 10 Pro Smart or is there another option from Creality?

Answer (score 2):

It does seem so. Both the [Creality Official site](https://www.creality3dofficial.com/products/sprite-extruder-direct) and [Amazon product page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B09SV276FX) list the CR 10 Smart Pro as compatible printers for this extruder.

As far as another option from Creality, to my knowledge, the Sprite Extruder is the only extruder that Creality makes/sells. (If there is another, I will update)

Comment: The Sprite requires a complete rewiring of the motherboard. It is not just a plug-and-play replacement.

Comment: If you are looking for a plug-and-play replacement, please include that in your question. I do believe I answered the question as it was written.